# Не работает autocomplete без библиотеки jquery с гугл сайта asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, autocomplete

Подскажите, что у меня не так? Не работает Autocomplete и Datepicker, если библиотека jquery не с сайта гугл, а с папки Scripts проекта.

Контроллер:

```
    public JsonResult GetSubs(string term)
    {
        var data = this.dbContext.Subdivisions.Where(b => b.Unit.ToLower().Contains(term.ToLower()))
            .Select(a => new { label = a.Unit, id = a.Id }).Take(5).ToList();
        return this.Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

View:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Subdivision, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SubdivisionId)
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Subdivision.Unit, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Subdivision.Unit, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
$(function () {
    $("input[type='date']")
        .datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' })
        .get(0).setAttribute("type", "text");
    $.datepicker.regional['ru'] = {
        prevText: 'Пред',
        nextText: 'След',
        monthNames: ['Январь', 'Февраль', 'Март', 'Апрель', 'Май', 'Июнь',
            'Июль', 'Август', 'Сентябрь', 'Октябрь', 'Ноябрь', 'Декабрь'],
        monthNamesShort: ['Янв', 'Фев', 'Мар', 'Апр', 'Май', 'Июн',
            'Июл', 'Авг', 'Сен', 'Окт', 'Ноя', 'Дек'],
        dayNames: ['воскресенье', 'понедельник', 'вторник', 'среда', 'четверг', 'пятница', 'суббота'],
        dayNamesShort: ['вск', 'пнд', 'втр', 'срд', 'чтв', 'птн', 'сбт'],
        dayNamesMin: ['Вс', 'Пн', 'Вт', 'Ср', 'Чт', 'Пт', 'Сб'],
        weekHeader: 'Не',
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        firstDay: 1,
        isRTL: false,
        showMonthAfterYear: false,
        yearSuffix: ''
    };
    $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['ru']);
    $.validator.addMethod('date',
        function (value, element) {
            var ok = true;
            try {
                $.datepicker.parseDate('yy-mm-dd', value);
            }
            catch (err) {
                ok = false;
            }
            return ok;
        });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#Subdivision_Unit').autocomplete({
        source: '/Home/GetSubs',
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $("#SubdivisionId").val(ui.item.id);
            this.value = ui.item.value;
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Бандл:

```
       bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquerymin").Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery.min.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/moment").Include(
            "~/Scripts/moment*"));

        // Используйте версию Modernizr для разработчиков, чтобы учиться работать. Когда вы будете готовы перейти к работе,
        // готово к выпуску, используйте средство сборки по адресу https://modernizr.com, чтобы выбрать только необходимые тесты.
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/datepicker").Include(
            "~/Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker*"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css", 
                  "~/Content/site.css"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui")
            .Include("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/jqueryui")
            .Include("~/Content/themes/base/all.css"));
```

Layout

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/moment")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/datepicker")
```

Answer (score 1):

Название элемента данных, отправляемых на сервер должно соответствовать названию парамeтра метода контроллера.

```
data: { term: request.term },
```

или

```
public JsonResult GetSubs(string prefix)
{
```

*Update*

Внимательнее с названиями свойств:

```js
var data = [{
  "label": "Квартиры и комнаты",
  "id": 1
}, {
  "label": "Коммерческая недвижимость",
  "id": 2
}, {
  "label": "Дома и коттеджи",
  "id": 3
}, {
  "label": "Земельные участки",
  "id": 4
}, {
  "label": "Недвижимость за рубежом",
  "id": 5
}];

var mapped = $.map(data, function(item) {
  return {
    label: item.label,
    value: item.id
  };
});
console.log(mapped);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: поправил, не работает. Такое ощущение, что вообще не срабатывает скрипт, как можно проверить на простом примере?

Comment: @e1ement напечатайте в адресной строке браузера `.../Home/GetSubs?term=aaa` и посмотрите, что возвращается

Comment: http://localhost:49641/Home/GetSubs?term=а (рус) [{"label":"Квартиры и комнаты","id":1},{"label":"Коммерческая недвижимость","id":2},{"label":"Дома и коттеджи","id":3},{"label":"Земельные участки","id":4},{"label":"Недвижимость за рубежом","id":5}]

Comment: в логе все 5 значений

Comment: @e1ement не понял последний комментарий

Comment: в console вижу 5 этих id со значениями, но после подключения библиотеки слетел datepicker в другом редактируемом поле

Comment: @e1ement в чьей консоли, у себя?

Comment: в хроме, console, там список из значений. Если убираю ваш код и возвращаю как у меня было, то в консоле 1:99 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at 1:99

Comment: @e1ement Я не понял, у Вас jQuery загружен в страницу?

Comment: <script src="/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.js"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/moment.js"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>

    
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>

Comment: @e1ement Это все прекрасно. Но как же быть с неопределенным `$`?

Comment: в 99 строке datepicker.     $(function () {
        $("input[type='date']")
            .datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' })
            .get(0).setAttribute("type", "text");

Comment: нашел проблему, если я в layout использую вашу ссылку на jquery.min.js, то у меня и datepicker работает и autocomplete. Если её убираю, то все ломается. Что может быть? Обновил вопрос на актуальный код.

Comment: @e1ement очевидно, у Вас нет файла `jquery-3.3.1.js` в папке `Scripts` корня сайта

Comment: есть [ссылка](https://ibb.co/fyxsi8)